# Random Count in a "return" without many code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I google for a solution that allows me to generate a random number between 1 and 6. i found this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Now i tryed to use it in my code:

```
$scope.getUserImage = function (user) {
    if (user.avatar) {
        return user.avatar;
    } else {
        return '/images/icons/user-' + user.gender((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.svg';
    }
};
```

but with this i get a error, it means that the user.gender isnt any function. I know this is a realy very basic question. I started new with JavaScript. I am a Designer normaly.

Comment: Put a `+` after `gender` if you want to concatenate those two values.

Comment: `console.log((Math.random() * 6) + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to add the strings together (called 'concatenate' since we're talking about strings), separate each with a `+` symbol. But the 1-6 logic is also wrong, you'll need to round those numbers down.

```
$scope.getUserImage = function (user) {
    if (user.avatar) {
        return user.avatar;
    } else {
        var randomNumberOneToSix = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        return '/images/icons/user-' + user.gender + randomNumberOneToSix + '.svg';
    }
};
```

Bonus tip: w3schools is not a great resource. Add 'mdn' to every search and use Mozilla's excellent documentation for learning about web technologies.

Comment: ahh thanks alot! but he outputs counts like: /images/icons/user-female5.488666894449929.svg i need only counts between 1 and 6... why he generate so much digits after the comma?

Comment: @SvenBudak: `5.48866689...` *is* between 1 and 6. Your W3Schools link shows you how to eliminate the decimal part if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson I'd suggest adding concatenate to the description vs. just 'add'.  As someone who was self taught early on, it was an invaluable word to add to a programmer's vocabulary. +1

Comment: For you, @Suirtimed, anything.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a "+" to concat gender change this line

```
return '/images/icons/user-' + user.gender((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.svg';
```

to

```
return '/images/icons/user-' + user.gender + ((Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '.svg';
```